# JTable displaying values wrong/not displaying whole values

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jtable

I have a file that's generated from another program, and I'm trying to create a different program that will create a JTable with files in it. I've already tried using StackOverflow tutorials to fix it, but I can't figure out what's wrong. I used a tutorial to help me create the JTable to begin with, so I can't even figure out where it went wrong.

This is the content of the file

**EDITED WITH CORRECT FILE INPUT**

```
 5|10.540000| 12.181217| 4482.000000| 109.155482| 12.020000| 8.563800| 4834.000000| 56.715967| 
 10|29.480000| 8.425604| 50772.000000| 563.527552| 33.000000| 5.844637| 4310.000000| 111.075842| 
 50|259.120000| 2.885537| 21648.000000| 114.723483| 267.920000| 1.648783| 17158.000000| 56.444652| 
 100|624.700000| 2.039771| 13300.000000| 21.205140| 633.140000| 1.202862| 15864.000000| 36.446637| 
 250|1887.700000| 1.377592| 41134.000000| 22.781148| 1896.880000| 0.693851| 41924.000000| 45.683431| 
 500|4291.800000| 0.836839| 191150.000000| 79.367962| 4294.560000| 0.457202| 80876.000000| 86.643983| 
 1000|9598.000000| 0.436951| 244238.000000| 149.945987| 9585.120000| 0.266139| 219474.000000| 184.652819| 
 10000|129582.240000| 0.129851| 1219346.000000| 9.823825| 129214.380000| 0.053029| 1410626.000000| 6.414845| 
 50000|764303.200000| 0.042775| 8392266.000000| 29.384328| 762430.500000| 0.024571| 8935228.000000| 14.952530| 
 100000|1628728.920000| 0.029737| 18302506.000000| 18.204143| 1624946.720000| 0.016495| 22086830.000000| 23.866814|
```

And this is the part of the code that fills the values:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        String filePath = "C:\\Users\\hafiz\\OneDrive\\Documents\\test\\file.txt";
        File file = new File(filePath);

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String[] columnNames = {
                "Size", "Iterative Avg Count", "Iterative Coef Count",
                    "Iterative Avg Time", "Iterative Coef Time", "Recurive Avg Count", 
                    "Recurive Coef Count", "Recurive Avg Time", "Recurive Coef Time"
            };
            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
            model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnNames);

            Object[] tableLines = br.lines().toArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < tableLines.length; i++) {
                String line = tableLines[i].toString().trim();
                String[] dataRow = line.split("|");
                model.addRow(dataRow);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Table.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
```

This is the whole code if it comes of any use:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author hafiz
 */
public class Table extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Table
     */
    public Table() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {

            }
        ));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

        jButton2.setText("Import Text");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 745, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(331, 331, 331)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 8, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 269, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        String filePath = "C:\\Users\\hafiz\\OneDrive\\Documents\\test\\file.txt";
        File file = new File(filePath);

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String[] columnNames = {
                "Size", "Iterative Avg Count", "Iterative Coef Count",
                    "Iterative Avg Time", "Iterative Coef Time", "Recurive Avg Count", 
                    "Recurive Coef Count", "Recurive Avg Time", "Recurive Coef Time"
            };
            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
            model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnNames);

            Object[] tableLines = br.lines().toArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < tableLines.length; i++) {
                String line = tableLines[i].toString().trim();
                String[] dataRow = line.split("|");
                model.addRow(dataRow);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Table.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Table.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Table.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Table.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Table.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Table().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

The first column (which is size) is empty for value records.

This is how the output looks right now[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two main issues:

1. Your input of |10.140000| 13.084819| 4392.000000| 82.699923| 11.900000| 10.118987| 5166.000000| 59.443868| starts with your separator, so the size column will be empty, because it will contain the substring left from the first | instance
2. Your input has 8 values, but you have 9 columns, so at least a column will have no values.

EDIT

You also need to escape the `|` character, so you will need to do something like

```
String[] dataRow = line.split("\\|");
```

Comment: Thank you! Why won't it display the whole number though? It's only displaying the first number of each value, even though it should be the whole thing including the decimals.

Comment: @nbaq can you make a screenshot about your JTable?

Comment: comparatively, the file now looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/CRfzUI9.png

Comment: @nbaq yes, you are right. Please take a look at the edit of my answer.

Comment: it worked! Thank you so much. I really appreciate it. I didn't even realize I'd have to escape that character.